# Margin bound for binary classification and Rademacher complexity

Tags: kernel-trick, statistical-learning, bounds, mathematical-statistics

In the [slides](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mls/lecture_4.pdf) (slide 29) of Mohri a margin bound for binary classification is derived:

$$R(h) \leq \hat{R}_\rho(h) + \frac{2}{\rho} \hat{R}_S(H) + 3\sqrt{\frac{\log \frac{2}{\delta}}{2m}}$$

Here $\hat{R}_\rho(h)$ is the empirical margin loss of $h$, $R(h)$ is the generalization error of $h$, and $\hat{R}_S(H)$ is the empirical Rademacher complexity of $H$. $\rho > 0$ is the desired margin. In all derivations of these kinds of bounds, it is mentioned that $\rho > 0 $ is fixed.

1) I was wondering, can we compute this bound on the generalization error for multiple values of $\rho$, and then take the one that is the tightest? Or is this not allowed since $\rho$ is fixed?

2) Another question that I have is the following. Must we fix the hypothesis class $H$ before we can compute the empirical Rademacher complexity, or is it possible to specify the hypothesis class after seeing all samples? To be more precise, I want a hypothesis class of the following form:
$$H = \{x \mapsto <w,\Phi(x_i)>: w = f(K,x)\}$$

Where $f$ is a function that depends on the kernel matrix $K$ of all samples: $$K(i,j) = <\Phi(x_i),\Phi(x_j)>$$ and another vector $x$. To train the classifier, I obtain $x$ by optimizing a SRM problem:

$$h^* = \underset{h \in H}{\text{argmin}}~ \lambda ||h||^2 + \sum_i L(h(x_i))$$

Since $h$ only depends on $f(K,x)$ the above minimization can be rewritten as a minimization in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) When you train your classifier or your regressor, the goal if to maximize $\rho$. It actually corresponds to the geometrical margin for the case of SVM classification!. So there is one value, the one you which is optimized.

Check slide 30. Here $\rho$, the margin, is introduced in an abstract way, using the properties of the Rademacher complexity to bound the empirical error, so you can have an estimate of how well your algorithm generalizes. Concretely, he introduces the Lipschitz function depicted in slide 28 (the hinge loss) to bind the 0-1 loss. It is just to get a bound on the Rademacher complexity.

Notice that, in principle, that value is arbitrary. But, in practice, you want the bound to be as tight as possible. And that corresponds to the maximum margin you are used to think of in geometrical terms.

What this bound is telling you is: given test data sampled from the same distribution as the training data (which is supposed to be stationary), how likely is that you perform as well on the new data as on the training data?. Is about analysing the stability of your classifier.

2) The hypothesis class is given by the choice you make of your kernel. Given the kernel, by the [Mercer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer's_theorem), the $\Phi$'s are also determined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still a bit uncertain about 2. The $\Phi$ might be determined, but that doesn't nececarily mean we know all values of $\Phi(x_i)$ for all $i$. Right? This [paper](http://ml.technion.ac.il/TMLC/El-YanivP09.pdf) indicates that the Transductive Rademacher complexity allows one to choose $H$ after observing all $x_i$, and implies that this is not allowed otherwise (for the regular empirical Rademacher complexity).

Comment: Very interesting paper. I think the confusion is that it actually refers to a different problem, that of transductive learning, which looks for a different type of error (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transduction_(machine_learning) and http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~dplewis/candidacy/gammerman98learning.pdf). Please refer again to what the bound is telling you in my answer in 1). Regretfully, I am not familiar with transductive learning.

Comment: Dear Juampa, I think you misunderstood. I'm interested in the inductive case. In the paper it says: (p.2) 'this bound is similar to known inductive Rademacher bounds..., it is fundamentally different in the sense that the transductive Rademacher complexity is computed with respect to the hypothesis space that can be chosen after observing unlabeled training and test examples. _This opportunity is unavailable in the inductive setting where the hypothesis space must be fixed before any example is observed_'. So I think h cannot depend on $f(K,x)$, since you need to know all $x_i$.

Comment: Furthermore, the kernel determines the mapping $\Phi$, but this doesn't nececarily mean we know $\Phi(x_i)$ for all $x_i$ (or that we have access to $x_i$). So, I think we cannot let $h$ depend on $K$, do you agree?

Comment: OK, now I understand. but in your question you ask whether you can use the expressions in the slides to approach that problem. So the answer is no, as I see it and, well, you already have the right paper. I hope we are now on the same page

Comment: It is not quite accurate to state that this is what you solved for; note that $\rho$ is not exactly the margin you optimize for - specifically, the Rademacher complexity is defined using a truncated loss function (i.e., the maximum loss is 1) while SVM does not truncate the loss function (so as to keep the problem convex). It isn't difficult to derive though what the (minimal) optimal $\rho$ would be (hint: look at the sub-gradient of the right-hand side with respect to $\rho$).